# Ansible - Change user password on Linux

Tags: linux, authentication, ansible

I'm doing some playbook to change username password on linux. I want to use the same playbook for all users.

What i am doing is:

```
    - name: change users password
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files: ['credentials.yml']
  tasks:
    - user:
        name: "{{ user_name }}"
        password: "{{ dynamic_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

And my file.yml:

```
credentials.yml
dynamic_password: "$6$mysecretsalt$QF9IdmmJLZWuEO8PKQ0w7c81Rre0hv.udU83ypIO3cG5DbAo90IXwHX6wcuhDJaLAkdE5KSSl9lKvdMFh810b."
generic_password: "$6$IxMDgSamMRSMAEY1$rfGAWC8xBgGMMGOFJXAMxnUuiKVKrH3SDOuNIrJpx4rMZy/FG5spqp1f9oSAcDBpTJ2vOK2rAboWHZ6Zn5qZm."
```

What i am executing:

```
ansible-playbook prueba81.yml --extra-vars "user_name=pepito type_password=dynamic_password"
```

What i want to do, is indicate in the command line, the user and what password (inside of the file yml) should it use. But seems that the variable type_password is not recognized.

Can you help me?.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Inputting authentication information directly in command line may lead to security problems because shell records your commands in history. In that sense putting username and password in files with good ownership and permission protection is better.

Comment: Mai, hello, thanks for the recomendation, but i'm doing this way to test it, in a test server,  then the playbooks will be executed it with ansible tower. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookup vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables) to reference the password indirectly. For example

```
  - user:
      name: "{{ user_name }}"
      password: "{{ my_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    vars:
      my_password: "{{ lookup('vars', type_password) }}"
```

You might want to set a default type. For example

```
  - user:
      name: "{{ user_name }}"
      password: "{{ my_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    vars:
      my_password: "{{ lookup('vars', type_password|default('dynamic_password')) }}"
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Looks like is doing something now, but the password is not working. The password hash in the shadow file is changing.

The hash i created with:
python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("dynauto*17", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'`

`- name: change users password
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files: ['credentials.yml']
  tasks:
    - user:
        name: "{{ user_name }}"
        password: "{{  my_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      vars:
        my_password: "{{ lookup('vars', type_password) }}"` 

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your extra-vars on the command line isn't setting type_password to the value of the variable dynamic_password.  You're literally setting the variable type_password to be the string "dynamic_password".

If you want to tell ansible what variable to use from the command line, you can do it several ways.  Here's one example:

> ansible-playbook prueba81.yml --extra-vars "user_name=pepito type_password=dynamic"

```
tasks:  
  - user:  
      name: "{{ user_name }}"  
      password: "{{ dynamic_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"  
    when type_password == "dynamic"
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response. I have the same problem that with the solution of Vladimir, the password in the shadow is changing, but is not working when i try. 

Could be how the hash in credentials.yml is quoted? Thanks in advance!